# Ansible: Include playbook according to inventory variable

Tags: ansible

I am trying to set up Ansible to be able to run a playbook according to what inventory group the host is in. For example, in the inventory, we have:

```
[group1]
host1.sub.domain.tld ansible_host=10.0.0.2
...
[group1:vars]
whatsmyplaybook=build-server.yml
```

Then we want to make a simple playbook that will more or less redirect to the playbook that is in the inventory:

```
---
- name: Load Playbook from inventory
  include: "{{hostvars[server].whatsmyplaybook}}"
```

Where the "`server`" variable would be the host's FQDN, passed in from the command line:

```
ansible-playbook whatsmyplaybook.yml -e "server=host1.sub.domain.tld"
```

Our reasoning for this would be to have a server bootstrap itself from a fresh installation (PXE boot), where it will only really know its FQDN, then have a firstboot script SSH to our Ansible host and kick off the above command. However, when we do this, we get the below error:

```
ERROR! 'hostvars' is undefined
```

This suggests that the inventory is not parsed until a `host` list is provided, which sucks a lot. Is there another way to accomplish this?

Comment: Why are you trying this at all? Ansible plays have `hosts` declaration which determines what group they are applied to. Any play you include must have this declaration and will run on all host groups that match.

Comment: @techraf "`Our reasoning for this would be to have a server bootstrap itself from a fresh installation (PXE boot), where it will only really know its FQDN`". We already have playbooks that work with filled out `hosts` declarations, but they have to be changed or otherwise run with too wide a scope when we rebuild a machine. Our goal is to eliminate the need for this, and allow a host that does not know its role/playbook to make Ansible run against it.

Answer (score 0):

A bit strange workflow, honestly.

Your setup doesn't work, because most of variables are not defined during playbook parse time.

You may be more lucky with defining single playbook with different plays for different groups (no need to set group var, just use correct host pattern (group name in my example)) and execute it limiting to specific host:

site.yml:

```
---
- hosts: group1
  tasks:
    - include: build-web-server-tasks.yml

- hosts: group2
  tasks:
    - include: build-db-server-tasks2.yml
```

command to provision specific server:

```
ansible-playbook -l host1.sub.domain.tld site.yml
```

Comment: We already have working playbooks for each host group, but they will either run against the whole group (not ideal), or have to be edited and called manually to run against freshly reloaded machines (which is what we are trying to eliminate the need for).

Comment: I guess this is the very reason behind `-l` switch: to limit host pattern without modifying playbook. Otherwise I don't understand the problem, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You can develop your own dynamic inventory file so that all machines which needs to be bootstrapped will automatically added into your inventory and  group respectively with out an manual entry in to the inventory file.

For developing dynamic inventory you can follow the below link:

http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_inventory.html

You can include multiple playbooks targeted to different groups as follows.

```
---
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - include: build-web-server-tasks.yml
      where: inventory_hostname in groups['group1']
    - include: build-db-server-tasks2.yml
      where: inventory_hostname in groups['group2']
```

*inventory_hostname is the name of the hostname as configured in Ansible’s inventory host file. This can be useful for when you don’t want to rely on the discovered hostname ansible_hostname or for other mysterious reasons. If you have a long FQDN, inventory_hostname_short also contains the part up to the first period, without the rest of the domain.*

Comment: The inventory is already complete with the requisite hosts, as I indicated in the question.